# How do set the image to the middle of a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to center this image but when i do it automatically goes to the nw corner but when i take that code out the image disappears

```
root = Tk()

def graph():
    
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Select File",  filetypes=[("PNG", "*.png"),("All files", "*")])
        #convert lena.jpg into tkinter photo image
            
    filewin = Toplevel(root)
    filewin.title(filename) 
    filewin.geometry('1150x550')

    global image 
    image = Image.open(filename)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    #create canvas to display picture
    w = Canvas(filewin, height=550, width=1150)
    w.photo = photo


    w.create_image(0,0,image = photo, anchor = "nw")
    w.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

    return image

graph()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're explicitly putting it in the upper-left corner, have you tried doing a little math to calculate the proper coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the center (x, y) of the canvas and create the image at that position with `anchor="c"`:

```py
# calculate the center of the canvas
x, y = w.winfo_reqwidth()/2, w.winfo_reqheight()/2
w.create_image(x, y, image=photo, anchor="c") # use anchor="c"
```